# Change List Item Permission via Web Services?

Tags: development, list, wss-3.0, web-services, security

Using web services, is there a way to assign a list item different security than the rest of the list?

Lets say I have 3 rows in the list and 2 different groups.

```
    1. A ; Group A & B can see
    2. B ; Group A & B can see
    3. C ; Group A & B can see
```

Next I add a new row via web services, but during the adding of this new row, I would also like to be able to change the row level permission to only allow Group B to see this new row #4

```
    4. D ; Group B can see.
```

What web service call can I make to do this?  Which asmx?

I am using MOSS 2007, and app works on a different machine, hence web services.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

From what I've seen, it is not possible to it with the out of the box web services.  [This blog article](http://www.codefornuts.com/2009/05/item-level-security-with-sharepoint-web.html) shows how to create your own web service to do that including the source code.